# secure websocket in closed or already closed mode

Tags: javascript, tomcat, ssl, https, websocket

I connected to the following site with HTTPS `https://localhost:8443/websocket/` which works fine and correctly with my self signed certificate in the latest stable **Google Chrome**. However when I try to send a message through the following JavaScript code through my secure websocket on the page I get a `WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state`

`<meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Tomcat WebSocket Chat</title>
        <script>
            var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080/websocket/echo");
            ws.onopen = function(){
            };
            ws.onmessage = function(message){
                document.getElementById("chatlog").textContent += message.data + "\n";
            };
            function postToServer(){
                ws.send(document.getElementById("msg").value);
                document.getElementById("msg").value = "";
            }
            function closeConnect(){
                ws.close();
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="chatlog" readonly></textarea><br/>
        <input id="msg" type="text" />
        <button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="postToServer()">Send!</button>
        <button type="submit" id="sendButton" onClick="closeConnect()">End</button>
    </body>
</html>`

Does anyone have a clue to why this is happening when I use secure websockets but the code works fine on a non `HTTPS` page with regular websockets? Also it is being ran through `tomcat 7.0.53`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8080/websocket/echo");` must be changed to the port that is being used for the local host which in this case is `8443` so it should now read `var ws = new WebSocket("wss://localhost:8443/websocket/echo");`